# Abort WaitAndRetryAsync policy?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, polly

I'd like to use `WaitAndRetryAsync` to help retry http 429 (throttling) errors. The retry delay is returned as a property on the exception itself.
But I need to add the accumulated time and abandon the retry loop if the overall duration exceeds a certain amount.

```
policy = Policy.Handle<DocumentClientException>(ex => ex.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)429)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(
        retryCount: retries,
        sleepDurationProvider: (retryCount, exception, context) => {
            DocumentClientException dce = exception as DocumentClientException;

            // Here I would like to check the total time and NOT return a RetryAfter value if my overall time is exceeded. Instead re-throw the 'exception'.

            return dce.RetryAfter;
    },
        onRetryAsync: async (res, timespan, retryCount, context) => {
    });
```

When the overall time is exceeded I'd like to re-throw the 'exception' handled in the `sleepDurationProvider`.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This first example below limits the *total waits between retries* to a total timespan `myWaitLimit`, but takes no account of how long the calls to CosmosDB spend before returning `DocumentClientException`.  Because Polly `Context` is execution-scoped, this is thread-safe.  Something like:

```
policy = Policy.Handle<DocumentClientException>(ex => ex.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)429)
.WaitAndRetryAsync(
    retryCount: retries,
    sleepDurationProvider: (retryCount, exception, context) => {
        DocumentClientException dce = exception as DocumentClientException;

        TimeSpan toWait = dce.RetryAfter;
        TimeSpan waitedSoFar;
        if (!Context.TryGetValue("WaitedSoFar", out waitedSoFar)) waitedSoFar = TimeSpan.Zero; // (probably some extra casting actually needed between object and TimeSpan, but this kind of idea ...)
        waitedSoFar = waitedSoFar + toWait;

        if (waitedSoFar > myWaitLimit)
            throw dce; // or use ExceptionDispatchInfo to preserve stack trace

        Context["WaitedSoFar"] = waitedSoFar; // (magic string "WaitedSoFar" only for readability; of course you can factor this out)
        return toWait;
    },
    onRetryAsync: async (res, timespan, retryCount, context) => {
});
```

---

An alternative approach could limit the *overall* execution time (when 429s occur) using a timing-out `CancellationToken`.  The below approach will not retry further after the `CancellationToken` has been signalled.  This approach is modelled to be close to the functionality requested in the question, but the timeout clearly only takes effect if a 429 response is returned and the `sleepDurationProvider` delegate is invoked.

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.CancelAfter(/* my timeout */);

var policy = Policy.Handle<DocumentClientException>(ex => ex.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)429)
.WaitAndRetryAsync(
    retryCount: retries,
    sleepDurationProvider: (retryCount, exception, context) => {
        if (cts.IsCancellationRequested) throw exception; // or use ExceptionDispatchInfo to preserve stack trace

        DocumentClientException dce = exception as DocumentClientException;
        return dce.RetryAfter;
    },
    onRetryAsync: async (res, timespan, retryCount, context) => {
});
```

If you don't wish to define `policy` in the same scope as using it and close over the variable `cts` (as the above example does), you can pass the `CancellationTokenSource` around using Polly `Context` as [described in this blog post](http://www.thepollyproject.org/2017/05/04/putting-the-context-into-polly/).

---

Alternatively, Polly provides a [`TimeoutPolicy`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout). Using [`PolicyWrap`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap) you can wrap this outside the retry policy.  A timeout can then be imposed on the overall execution whether a 429 occurs or not.

If the strategy is intended to manage Cosmos DB async calls which do not inherently take a `CancellationToken`, you would need to use [`TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#pessimistic-timeout) if you wanted to *enforce* timeout at that time interval.  However, note from the wiki how `TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic` operates: it allows the calling thread to walk away from the uncancellable call, but doesn't unilaterally cancel the uncancellable call. That call might either later fault, or continue to completion.

---

Obviously, consider what is best from among the above options, according to your context.

Comment: Thanks @mt, this helps quite a bit. The core concept I learned is that I can throw an exception within sleepDurationProvider, this must be a general Polly convention not specific to the WaitAndRetryAsync policy that I missed. My goal was to not abandon any non-cancelable calls, but instead just bubble up the last throttling error to the caller as-is, likely with ExceptionDispatchInfo. So I'll be keeping track of the total elapsed time in the Context.

Comment: Is it possible to exit without throwing the exception?